# LG G2 Native SIP client (where Is It?)

Tags: htc-desire-z, voip, sip, lg

For some reason I couldn't find the native SIP client on this Phone. On my Note 2 N7100 it's under Settings-> Call Settings-> Accounts

Will someone please show me where it's hidden?

Note: LG G2 D802 international version

Comment: Maybe it went to the same place as [Where did the SIP settings go to on my LG Optimus 4X?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/45633/16575)

Comment: @Izzy

Tried that link before posting here...

It won't work as there's a missing process from LG G2 firmware. LG took that process out. This is what happen - "unfortunately, the process com.android.phone has stopped."

Comment: That is what happens *when*? When you try "starting" the action from the shortcut? Happens to a lot of them, yes. Continue looking for another one with a similar name, that did it for me. In the worst case, try them all (oops).