# How to make incoming SIP calls work on Android 4.x?

Tags: calls, google-voice, voip, sip

I have a SIP account which I entered into the "Internet Call Settings" of the native android phone app. I am able to place outgoing SIP calls, but no luck with the incoming ones. I am new to the SIP subject, so I was wondering what I am missing and a description how incoming SIP works would be a plus!

**Info:**

- Phone: Nexus 4
- OS: Android 4.3
- SIP Provider: didlogic (sip.didlogic.net)
- Google voice account: available

Feel free to ask for more info. I want to figure this thing out.

**EDIT:** I am on t-mobile $30 unlimited data and text plan, in case it makes any difference, but it still does not work when im at home on wi-fi.

**EDIT 2:** Let me ask this: How does the inbound SIP work? Does the phone or wi-fy needs to constantly listen for a signal at the port 5060 or is the phone does a simple alike keep-alive connection with the SIP server in the background?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android phones with native SIP client?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35602/android-phones-with-native-sip-client)

Comment: Not a duplicate to that one. OP writes he already set up an account successfully and can make outgoing calls, just not receive inbound calls, so this is different.

Comment: Yeah, I did not really need the setup instructions and I do have the "receive incoming calls" option turned on.

Answer (score 1):

On Android 4.1.x with enabled native SIP call stack:
Internet Call Settings > Enable Incoming Calls

If you set your DID account correctly and your SIP provider supports DID, then you will be able to receieve calls.

[image: Enable incoming calls]

Comment: I do have the option to receive internet calls turned on. What does correct DID acount setup intails?

Comment: You need a VOIP Provider that allows you to have a Direct Inward Calling number. You need to buy a DID phone number or enable that service in your VOIP provider. I don't know how to setup a DID Number which you've bought form another provider thatn your VOIP provider. But if you use a provider, that offers both, then you can be sure the inward calling works if you enable it in the settings. example: voip-club.biz

Answer (score 0):

Install the app Sipdroid and setup/use with Google Voice. This is the way I use SIP and it works perfectly.